# Disable editing after commit in Leaflet.Editable

Tags: leaflet

I'm using `Leaflet.Editable` to draw polygon on my map, but I don't want to edit the polygon that I'm drawing. I want it to be fixed on my map.
How can I do that?

Comment: Have you considered using [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw)? As far as I can tell from the API, editing is disabled by default: https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#options